# Does GetVolumeInformation() returns a unique volume serial number?

Tags: winapi

The documentation for [GetVolumeInformation()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> This function returns the volume serial number that the operating
>   system assigns when a hard disk is formatted. To programmatically
>   obtain the hard disk's serial number that the manufacturer assigns,
>   use the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) Win32_PhysicalMedia
>   property SerialNumber.

Does Windows assigns a unique volume serial number, or could multiple machines have the same volume serial number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume serial number is a `DWORD`. There are 2<sup>32</sup> different possible values of a `DWORD`. Therefore it stands to reason that since there are a finite number of possible values, and an unbounded number of volumes in the world, that there could be multiple volumes sharing the same serial number.

Answer (score 1):

If you clone a partition, it will have the same volume serial number as the source disk.  There is no enforcement that the volume serial number is unique to a running system.

However, a GUID volume path (such as `\\?\Volume{c111cc73-4a4a-11eb-ac1e-4c3488ecf035}`) will be unique on a running system, even when a disk is cloned.